# Sorting a subsequence of an array without an additional array

Tags: ruby, algorithm, sorting

I'm new to programming. I start to learn Ruby freshly and I can't understand how to implement an algorithm for permuting negative(or positive) elements of an array without using an additional array.
For example:
Like this: [-10, 3, -1, 0, -9 ] -> [-10, 3, -9, 0, -1 ] (sort only negatives)
Either that: [-5, 5, -8, 2, 1] ->  [-5, 1, -8, 2, 5] (sort only positives)

Comment: Do you know how to write a regular sort function without an additional array (quicksort would fit this requirement, for instance)? Can you modify *that* code to ignore certain elements?

Comment: You can swap elements in the array. E.g. `arr[0], arr[1] = arr[1], arr[0]`. Hopefully that would help you get started

Comment: @maxpleaner: That will create a two-element array, at least semantically. I believe JRuby and TruffleRuby can optimize it away, but according to the language semantics, it is always there.

Comment: @KirKon753 : Is it a coding challenge to do it without additional arrays, or are you worried about performance? From the viewpoint of legibility, the cleanest solutions would use an auxiliary array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def sort_positives(arr)
  (arr.size-1).times do |i|
    next if arr[i] <= 0
    smallest = i
    (i+1..arr.size-1).each do |j|
      smallest = j if arr[j] > 0 && arr[j] < arr[smallest]
    end
    if smallest > i
      tmp = arr[i]
      arr[i] = arr[smallest]
      arr[smallest] = tmp
    end
  end
  arr
end
```

```
arr = [-2, 5, 3, -4, 6, 1, -3]
sort_positives arr
  #=> [-2, 1, 3, -4, 5, 6, -3]
arr
  #=> [-2, 1, 3, -4, 5, 6, -3]
```

`sort_negatives` is a straightforward modification to `sort_positives`.

Answer (score 1):

```rb
def swap(arr, i, j)
  arr[i] = arr[i] ^ arr[j]
  arr[j] = arr[j] ^ arr[i]
  arr[i] = arr[j] ^ arr[i]
end

def sort_negative(arr)
  size = arr.size
  i = 0
  while i < size - 1
    next if arr[i] > 0 # first index of negative number
    next_neg = 0
    min_neg = i
    (i + 1).upto(size - 1) do |j|
      if arr[i] < 0 && arr[j] < 0
        next_neg = j if next_neg == 0
        min_neg = j if arr[min_neg] > arr[j]
      end
    end
    swap(arr, i, min_neg) if min_neg > i
    if next_neg > 0
      i = next_neg # jump to next negative number
    else
      break
    end
  end
end

arr = [-10, 0, 2, 6, 10, -1, 7, 20, 1, 0, -9, 13, 6, 88, -11, -156]
sort_negative(arr)
puts arr.inspect # [-156, 0, 2, 6, 10, -11, 7, 20, 1, 0, -10, 13, 6, 88, -9, -1]
```

Comment: `arr[i], arr[min_neg] = arr[min_neg], arr[i]` will create an array, which is not allowed, according to the OP.

Comment: @JörgWMittag i replace by XOR operator.